# parsing an html table in C got funny

Tags: c++, c

i am free today so i said why not to try to parse an html table in c(and a bit of c++ just for streams) so i did the following

```
int main()
{
    char html[] ="<tr> \
        <td>row 1, cell 1 < / td > \
        <td>row 1, cell 2 < / td > \
        < / tr> \
        <tr> \
        <td>row 2, cell 1 < / td > \
        <td>row 2, cell 2 < / td > \
        < / tr> ";

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(html)/sizeof(html[0])); i++)
{
    if (html[i] == '<')
    {
        for (int j = i + 1;; j++)
        {
            if (html[j] == '>')
            {
                for (int c = j + 1;; c++)
                {
                    if (html[c] == '<')
                        break;
                    std::cout << html[c];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

and i got the following the screen to the left was my first try, but i made it much better in my second try to the right

[image]

could anyone make it even better by hiding those unneeded symboles?

after using strlen(html) i also go this

[image]

Comment: Those unneeded symbols are a clear indication you are going outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: Your inner loops doesn't check if they goes out of bounds.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but it will break when it finds the end tag

Comment: Cast `sizeof(html)/sizeof(html[0])` to `int`.

Comment: @haccks: alternatively the `/sizeof(html[0])` could be removed.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: @user1492051: Not after the ending `< / tr >` tag it won't.

Comment: I'd guess that the index into your html array is out of bounds at some point.

Comment: @haccks @ctor Alternatively use `strlen(html)`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; Yes. This would be better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i did check what i got in the last image, something lovely

Comment: Rather than nested loops, you should try and implement this as a *state machine*. It would be *much* more intelligible, efficient and extendable.

Comment: I can see your passwords in that screenshot!  (not really, but be careful about posting random data like this...)

Comment: These are not "unneeded symbols" - they are a sign that your code has a fundamental flaw and is committing potential memory violations!

Comment: @user1492051: Yeah sorry, I forgot to change the `break` into a `return`, so that you can escape the nested loops of death without duplicating the exit condition at each stage. This only illustrates the difficulty to maintain such a code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not hide these funny symbols unless you allowed me remote access to your computer. I could, however, suggest you check the termination condition of your inner loop, like so:

```
for (int c = j + 1;; c++)
{
    if ((html[c] == '<') || c >= strlen(html))
        return 0;
    std::cout << html[c];
}
```

Btw:

- the sizeof thing seems a bit odd.

  - `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so the division is an overkill.
  - a parser is of limited use if it can only work on a constant input, so I would rather use `strlen` here (possibly caching it into a local, if performance is an issue :)).
- your 3 embedded loops are leading you to the right edge of the screen fast.
  You won't have a real parser work that way.
  The usual method is to use a finite state machine, with a tokenizer dividing the input into manageable chunks.

EDIT:

I used `strlen` to make the code duplication with your outer loop more apparent.
You could indeed test the string termination to avoid a textbook case of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm), but that would not save the global design.

EDIT (bis)

As Charles Beattie noted, one of the main drawbacks of this approach is to consider the whole input as a big lump of text, making the processing awkward and slow.

This is one of the benefits of the tokenizer approach: extract small syntaxic elements and work with them as abstract objects instead of wading through the whole input.

Comment: Surely just check for null. I.e. `html[c] != '\0'`

Comment: Well turning this code into a real parser would require to dump the whole loop anyway, so performance is not really an issue here, IMHO. I used `strlen` to make the code duplication with the outer loop more apparent.

Comment: Why have the termination check there? Why not simply put it as a loop condition?

Comment: I wouldn't use `strlen` if the content is huge.

Comment: @CharlesBeattie I wouldn't use this code to parse a goldfish's speech, let alone the complete edition of the Merriam-Webster :).

Comment: @kuroineko i dont know i am a noob but i though this would be more performant if i care about parsing tables only

Comment: @user1492051 I did not mind to belittle your efforts. Your initial idea is not bad, but as far as parsers are concerned, performance is not the key point. Maintenability is more of a concern. What will really limit your throughput is either the disk I/O or the cpu spent by the higher levels of your interpreter/compiler (costly algorithms for code optimization, for instance). So usually optimizing the parser is a bit like optimizing the outer loop of an o(n^3) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking whether you run off the end of your arrays. Try

Changing

```
for (int j = i + 1;; j++)
```

to

```
for (int j = i + 1;html[j]!='\0'; j++)
```

and changing

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(html)/sizeof(html[0])); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; html[i]!='\0'; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking for array bounds inside the inner loops and you're reading memory belonging to your process (that's why you're not getting any access violation) but that doesn't pertain to your array.

The correct code should be:

```
int main()
{
    char html[] ="<tr> \
<td>row 1, cell 1 < / td > \
<td>row 1, cell 2 < / td > \
< / tr> \
<tr> \
<td>row 2, cell 1 < / td > \
<td>row 2, cell 2 < / td > \
< / tr> ";

    int totalsize = (int)(sizeof(html)/sizeof(html[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < totalsize; i++)
    {
        if (html[i] == '<')
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; /*j < totalsize*/; j++)
            {
                if (html[j] == '>')
                {
                    if(j == 132)
                        printf("ewa");
                    for (int c = j + 1; /*c < totalsize*/; c++)
                    {
                        if (html[c] == '<') {
                            i = c - 1;
                            std::cout << endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        std::cout << html[c];
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the two added bound checkings to the inner for loops.

Also: what you were dumping was the XML manifest file for your executable, mapped directly into memory :)

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

 <dependency>

  <dependentAssembly>

  <assemblyIdentity 

   type="win32" 

   name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 

   version="6.0.0.0" 

   processorArchitecture="x86" 

   publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 

   language="*"

  />

  </dependentAssembly>

 </dependency>

 <dependency>

  <dependentAssembly>

  <assemblyIdentity 

   type="win32" 

   name="Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus" 

   version="1.1.0.0" 

   processorArchitecture="x86"

   publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"

   language="*"

  />

  </dependentAssembly>

 </dependency>

 </assembly>
```

The dumping started with the first **<** encountered and ended when a 00 (null character) was encountered (at the end of the xml file, more or less..)